# Understanding pci address in lspci/dmesg

Tags: pcie, pci

When looking for the pci devices on the host machine, I have seen something like this in `lspci`:

```
....
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x8 Controller (rev 06)
....
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V (rev 04)
....
04:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 41)
```

and something like this in `dmesg`:

```
....
[    0.617223] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000e4000-0x000e7fff window]
[    0.624701] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0xbfa00000-0xfeafffff window]
[    0.632182] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-3e]
[    0.637685] pci 0000:00:00.0: [8086:0c00] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.637887] pci 0000:00:01.0: [8086:0c01] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.637938] pci 0000:00:01.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.638163] pci 0000:00:01.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.643883] pci 0000:00:01.1: [8086:0c05] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.643934] pci 0000:00:01.1: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
....
```

In `lspci`, the addresses seem to have 3 parts and in `dmesg` they seem to have 4 parts. What all can I understand by looking at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lspci` without any flags lists `bus:device.function`.

`dmesg` lists `domain:bus:device.function`, where domain is the root complex.

More here: https://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Bus:Device.Function_(BDF)_Notation

If you do `lspci -D`, it shows domain also, same as what you see in dmesg.

`lspci -t` also shows domain.